# Custom Expression to Define Width and Height in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm new in WPF so this is a very dummy question.

In Visual Studio -> Properties when I select a StackPanel (for example), I have the property Width. In this property I can click in the little square on the right and a menu is open. One of the option in the menu is "Custom Expression"

**So here is my question:**
Is possible to define Width and Height base in a Mathmatic expression?

```
<StackPanel Width="{Parent.Width - 100}">
</StackPanel>
```

Or something like that?

**EDIT**
I'm asking this because i'm intend to create a StackPanel that need to have a width 100 pixels lower than the Window. When window size was changed the StackPanel need to change to corresponding to this rule.

Comment: No.  You could create a custom binding, but that's probably way overkill.  You're experiencing an X/Y problem.  You think the solution is X.  The actual solution is Y.  You should [edit] and explain the issue you're trying to solve with this imaginary expression type.

Comment: Converter and pass Parent width.  But if you put a StackPanel in Grid.Column it will get the width of the column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default you cannot, and you have to use converters. Of course, especially since you are new in WPF, writing converters over and over for every simple operation like that might feel painful to you. So there are some custom markup extensions to reduce that pain. For example: https://quickconverter.codeplex.com/ (but there are others). With them it looks like that:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"                        
    xmlns:qc="http://QuickConverter.CodePlex.com/"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="500" Width="500" x:Name="self">
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Rectangle Fill="Red" 
           Width="{qc:Binding '$P-100', P={Binding ElementName=self, Path=ActualWidth}}" 
           Height="{qc:Binding '$P-100', P={Binding ElementName=self, Path=ActualHeight}}" />
</Grid>
</Window>
```

Here we bound width and height of a rectangle to parent "self" element dimensions minus 100, without use of explicit converters.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a binding to the parent element's width/height. However, instead of doing that, why not use the dynamic layout and just define your child container with a margin - in your example 50px - so that its width would be 100px less than the parent container.

So the answer to the theoretical question of "Can I set a calculated value of a property based on another element?" is yes, use a binding with a converter that performs the necessary calculation.

To the more important question of "Is there a simpler way to do create a responsive layout that takes the parent container into account?" the answer is also yes, use container composition with margins, padding and alignment to get the desired effect.